# Determining how to properly queue work when network client connects

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool

I have been reading about `Threadpool.QueueUserWorkItem` (what I've been using), `Task.Run` and `Task.Factory.StartNew` and am still unclear as to what the right option is here. It seems since my work is not CPU bound, I should probably not use `Task.Run`

I have my own thread running that waits for connections:

```
Thread listenThread = new Thread(() => ListenForConnection());
listenThread.Name = "lThread";
listenThread.IsBackground = true;
listenThread.Start();
```

and inside that I am simply doing:

```
tlist = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip.ToString()), 27275);
tlist.Start();

while (isRunning) {
     try {
          var client = await tlist.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
          ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(HandleClient, client);
     }
     catch (Exception) { }
}
```

`HandleClient` parses the message the client sends, and either creates an instance of a simple class or updates an existing one if the client already exists, stores references to the connection, and also updates a few UI elements.

Is `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` the preferred method here or am I way off?

Edit: just to note, the `HandleClient` function usually takes between 5 and 30 ms, so not very heavy work

Comment: Thread and ThreadPool is a little bit old. The modern one is Task.Fastory.StartNew and Task.Run. Both are ThreadPool with better functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QueueUserWorkItem`, `StartNew` and `Run` are more or less equivalent. I'd pick `Task.Run` because it is the most modern way to do it.

The way you have done it is totally OK. You have chosen a synchronous `HandleClient` implementation which forces you to handle the connection on a separate thread. Note, that this can consume many resources in case of many concurrent connections. If you are not interested in that scenario this is not a problem. Otherwise, it is a dealbreaker.

In case you make `HandleClient` truly asynchronous and non-blocking you do not need to push that call onto the thread-pool. My advice is to still do that because it has very little downside and it protects you against an overly long synchronous initial part of that method.

`catch (Exception) { }` this I don't understand. This might hide bugs. Also, if there is an error accepting most likely it is a permanent error. This kind of error handling will turn the loop into a busy loop consuming 100% of one CPU code. Move the catch outside of the loop.

Comment: The nature of how this application will work means that only one person can be physically interacting with it at any given time, but there may be x (up to 15) clients connected and waiting at any time, so _many_ concurrent connections are not too much of a concern. I also do some UI work in `HandleClient`, currently with `Dispatcher.Invoke`, which maybe isn't the best method? You are right of course about the catch, I will add more specific error handling there and alert the user to network issues.

Comment: Yes, 15 is not many. UI benefits greatly from async IO and await. Very productive. I find it a bit dirty to have the network layer know about the UI. But since that is already your approach consider not using Task.Run and using await inside of HancleClient. You will be able to delete all Dispatcher.Invoke calls and still have a responsive UI.

Comment: The other approach is to change nothing and use what you have because it's OK.

Comment: That is something I was wondering about as well. I'm not sure where I would use `await` in my `HandleClient` function because there simply isn't much going on in the function. I have a `ObservableCollection<Machine> activeMachines = new ObservableCollection<Machine>();` Which holds all of the information about the client. For the most part I am only adding or updating the class elements in that list, so the operations are very fast. So maybe there isn't really anything to `await` on in there? Maybe I can stick with `QueueUserWorkItem`

Comment: Normally, there is a read loop somewhere for each socket. But reviewing that would be for another question. Sounds like you have a working solution.

Comment: My messages usually do not exceed 100 bytes, and only over a local network so I usually do not have read loops, just a call to `Stream.Read`, but I may see about `ReadAsync` or the likes. Thanks for the replies

Comment: Sounds like the classic bug where you assume that a single read will read the entire message.

Comment: That is an interesting problem because in many C# applications using TCP I never never seen it happen, I have only ever _heard_ of people talk about it. Maybe it happens with large messages? Or over the internet?

Comment: Alright, it could happen anytime but in practice it happens when the write size goes over one packet or packets are coalesced so that you read multiple messages at a time. Sometimes the sender changes it's serialization algorithm and breaks the receiver with differently sizes packets. It's easy to avoid with BinaryReader.ReadBytes which reads an exact amount.

Comment: It's true that it often does not happen in practice. For that reason a lot of socket software must be totally broken.

Comment: I suppose with `Stream.Read` I also specify the amount to read, which for me is `buffer.Length`. I should keep an eye on that though, and possibly be ready to implement a read loop if that becomes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would say like this:

```
var tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 80);
tcpListener.Start();
while (true)
{
  var tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    // Do whatever you like with your TcpClient
  });
}
```